# Is x in int(x) numeric/non-numeric string?

Tags: python, type-conversion

In the code below, `int(x)` throws an exception. I understand that `x` should be a string but -numeric or non-numeric string?

```
def temp_convert(var):
   try:
      return int(var)
   except ValueError, Argument:
      print "The argument does not contain numbers\n", Argument

# Call above function here.
temp_convert("xyz")
```

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a great resource to get you started on that. -1, don’t take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I’ll gladly revert it. Good luck with your code! Personally I think it’d be good to work on list of question specific things that are poorly written.

Comment: @Darrel Lee: looks like Python

Comment: @Butters: Mind also formatting `int(x)`, and format subsequent references to `x` accordingly?

Comment: It is still not entirely clear what you are asking, does the provided answer adequately address your question?

Comment: I edited the question hope its clear now and I am new here, i dont get what formatting int(x) needs...could you illustrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you supply as the function argument has to be representable as an integer. What would you consider the numerical representation of `"xyz"` to be?

If you pass the function string representations of numbers, positive or negative, then you won't trigger the exception.

When numbers are encoded as strings there are no problems,

```
>>> int("10")
10
>>> int("-10")
-10
```

When symbols that aren't readily represented by a number is supplied to the function the exception will triggered,

```
>>> int("-10a")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-10a'
```

`int(x)` does not accept floating-point numbers either:

```
>>> int("10.0")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10.0'
```